# Arduino HTTPClient not working

Tags: httpclient, arduino

I have an Arduino with an Ethernet shield.

I have the httpclient library, and I am trying to run the PachubeClient example.

When I compile, it gives me many errors:

```
PachubeClient.cpp:25:25: error: Credentials.h: No such file or directory
PachubeClient.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
PachubeClient:47: error: 'ssid' was not declared in this scope
PachubeClient:47: error: 'passphrase' was not declared in this scope
PachubeClient:55: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
PachubeClient:95: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using the PachubeClient code from here: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PachubeCient?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played around with the Arduino development environment at all but that error message means you're either missing the Credentials.h file or the compiler doesn't know where to find it. Verify that the file exists and then check your compiler settings to make sure that you're passing it the path to the header files.